# rspec controller spec for create action with factory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, controller, rspec-rails

For some reason my controller specs for create action don't work. What did I miss?

factories

```
factory :profile do
  first_name { "John" }
  last_name { "Doe" }
  job_title { Faker::Name.title }
  company { "Faskyn" }
  avatar { Faker::Avatar.image }
  location { Faker::Address.city }
  description { Faker::Lorem.sentence }
  phone_number { Faker::PhoneNumber.cell_phone }
  user
end

factory :product, class: Product do
  name { Faker::Commerce.product_name }
  company { Faker::Company.name }
  website { 'https://example.com' }
  oneliner { Faker::Lorem.sentence }
  description { Faker::Lorem.paragraph }
  user
  trait :product_with_nested_attrs do
    before(:create) do |product|
      product.product_competitions << build(:product_competition, product: product)
      product.product_usecases << build(:product_usecase, product: product)
      product.product_features << build(:product_feature, product: product)
      product.industries << build(:industry)
    end
  end
end
```

profiles_controller_spec

```
describe "POST create" do
  before(:each) do
    login_user
  end
  context "with valid attributes" do

    it "saves the new profile in the db" do
      expect{ post :create, user_id: @user.id, profile: attributes_for(:profile, user: @user) }.to change(Profile, :count).by(1)
    end

    before(:each) do
      post :create, user_id: @user.id, profile: attributes_for(:profile, user: @user)
    end

    it { is_expected.to redirect_to add_socials_user_profile_path(@user) }
  end
end
```

error for profiles_controller_spec

```
ProfilesController POST create with valid attributes saves the new profile in the db
 Failure/Error: expect{ post :create, user_id: @user.id, profile: attributes_for(:profile, user: @user) }.to change(Profile, :count).by(1)
   expected #count to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0
```

products_controller_spec

```
context "POST create" do
  context "with valid attributes" do

    it "saves the new product in the db" do
      product_attrs = attributes_for(:product, :product_with_nested_attrs, user: @user)
      expect{ post :create, product: product_attrs }.to change{ Product.count }.by(1)
    end

    it { is_expected.to redirect_to product_path(Product.last) }
  end
end
```

errors for products_controller_spec

```
ProductsController when user is logged in POST create with valid attributes saves the new product in the db
 Failure/Error: expect{ post :create, product: product_attrs }.to change{ Product.count }.by(1)
   expected result to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0

ProductsController when user is logged in POST create with valid attributes
 Failure/Error: it { is_expected.to redirect_to product_path(Product.last) }

 ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"products", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

Comment: You've shown your factories, your specs and your failure messages, but you haven't shown any of the software under test, which includes your routes, your controllers and, unless you're mocking out the ActiveRecord calls, your models. Normally, that would make it hard for someone to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In `profiles_controller_spec`, you have a `before_each` which is creating the user before your first example executes, so an additional create is not going to bump the profile count. Note that placing a `before_each` after an example (`it`) does not change the fact that all `before_each` blocks at a given level are executed before any of the contained examples.'

As for the `products_controller_spec` failures, you would need to show more of the code (e.g. relevant variables and `before` blocks in containing blocks, code under test, etc.).

Comment: Peter, as for profiles: I could solve the problem by putting `@user.profile.destroy` before the expectation in the `saves the new profile in the db` test. I guess that't not the best way to do it. Could you provide some code how you would do it?  As for product I just posted  a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36827856/rspec-shoulda-setting-up-data Could you pls take a look at that as well? I guess the problem is similar. I don't really get how to setup the data properly. If you know a good resource, pls let me know.