# rspec + shoulda: setting up data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, shoulda

I have the following test. There are three `it` blocks. The first one doesn't use `shoulda` unlike the other two.

If I don't use the `before` block with `post :create, product: attrs` then the first test fails as expected. But If I put the `before` block there then the first test fails, but the other two pass. I have a uniqueness validation on product name, but that shouldn't be the problem as I'm using sequence with factory.

What should I do? How should I generally setup the data for testing when there are rspec and shoulda matchers present at the same time?

```
describe "when user logged in" do
  before(:each) do
    login_user #logged in user is available by calling @user
  end

  context "POST create" do
    context "with valid attributes" do
      let!(:profile) { create(:profile, user: @user) }
      let!(:industry) { create(:industry) }
      let!(:attrs) { attributes_for(:product, user_id: @user.id, industry_ids: [ industry.id ]).merge(
          product_features_attributes: [attributes_for(:product_feature)],
          product_competitions_attributes: [attributes_for(:product_competition)],
          product_usecases_attributes: [attributes_for(:product_usecase)]
        ) }

      it "saves the new product in the db" do
        expect{ post :create, product: attrs }.to change{ Product.count }.by(1)
      end

      #If I don't use this the 2 tests below fail. If I use it, then the test above fails.
      # before do
      #   post :create, product: attrs
      # end

      it { is_expected.to redirect_to product_path(Product.last) }
      it { is_expected.to set_flash.to('Product got created!') }
    end
  end
end
```

factories

```
factory :product, class: Product do
  #name { Faker::Commerce.product_name }
  sequence(:name) { |n| "ABC_#{n}" }
  company { Faker::Company.name }
  website { 'https://example.com' }
  oneliner { Faker::Lorem.sentence }
  description { Faker::Lorem.paragraph }
  user
end
```

Comment: Have you considered using different context blocks? This will allow you to have separate before blocks.

Comment: Petr, I did. I just don't know what the proper way is to do. On the top of that I'd like to understand the root of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have it both ways. If you execute the method you are testing in the `before`, then you can't execute it again to see if it changes the `Product` count. If you don't execute it in your before, then you must execute it in your example and therefore can't use the `is_expected` one liner format.

There are a variety of alternatives. Here is one that incorporates the execution of the method into all the examples.

```
describe "when user logged in" do
  before(:each) do
    login_user #logged in user is available by calling @user
  end

  describe "POST create" do
    subject(:create) { post :create, product: attrs }
    context "with valid attributes" do
      let!(:profile) { create(:profile, user: @user) }
      let!(:industry) { create(:industry) }
      let!(:attrs) { attributes_for(:product, user_id: @user.id, industry_ids: [ industry.id ]).merge(
          product_features_attributes: [attributes_for(:product_feature)],
          product_competitions_attributes: [attributes_for(:product_competition)],
          product_usecases_attributes: [attributes_for(:product_usecase)]
        ) }

      it "saves the new product in the db" do
        expect{ create }.to change{ Product.count }.by(1)
      end

      it("redirects") { expect(create).to redirect_to product_path(Product.last) }
      it("flashes") { expect(create).to set_flash.to('Product got created!') }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Peter, thanks for the answer! Don't you know a good resource, in which the different solutions are combined or compared to each other? I've read a lot about `let`, `subject`, `before`, `rspec matchers` and `shoulda matchers`, but all the resources explained them in isolation. When it comes to using them together it can be pretty confusing.

Comment: Peter, pls also see my prev comment. Are you sure you can pass the block with `{ }` like `it "redirects" { expect(create).to redirect_to product_path(Product.last) }` ? For some reason it only works with `do` + `end` for me.

Comment: You're absolutely right about the braces. You can't omit parentheses on a method invocation and append a block. You have to either use `do` `end` for the block or include parentheses. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: As far as rspec "style" resources are concerned, I'm afraid I don't have an answer for you, although it's something I feel I should be able to comment on. If I decided to look into it, I'll add a comment here at a later date.